# laravel where a payload data of column is met

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called MyModel. One of the columns is called "payload" and the column stores a json data. A sample of the data looks thus:

```js
{
    "ProductCode": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "My Service",
    }
    
}
```

My intention is to fetch the table collection like this:

```js
$myCollection = MyModel::where('payload', 1)->get();
```

The condition I want met is to return data that the **id** of **productCode** of the **payload** column is 1

How do I write the query please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```php
$myCollection = MyModel::whereJsonContains('payload', ['productCode' => ['id' => 1]])->get();
```

Comment: I have a part 2 to this question. Hopefully, you can help on that as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483157/laravel-wherein-implementation-of-wherejsoncontains