# Laravel whereIn implementation of whereJsonContains

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code that works fine and returns 1 item collection:

```
$myCollection = MyModel::whereJsonContains('payload->ProductCode->id', "1")->get();
```

I however want to fetch the $myCollection  not just when the value is 1 but when it is contained in one of many array items.

```
 $array = [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3];
 $myCollection = MyModel::whereJsonContains('payload->ProductCode->id', $array)->get();
```

**UPDATES**
When I try this code it return an empty data. I mean when I use **1** instead of **"1"**. Could that be the reason why it doesn't work when I use an array?

```js
$myCollection = MyModel::whereJsonContains('payload->ProductCode->id', 1)->get();
```

A sample of what the payload contains is this. I suppose that could give more clarity to my question:

```js
{
    "ProductCode": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "My Service",
    }
    
}
```

Running the above code returns an empty data. How do I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow your query as below.

```
$array = [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3];

// Eloquent
PaymentTransaction::whereJsonContains('payload->ProductCode->id',$array)->get();;

 // or
PaymentTransaction::jsonContains('payload->ProductCode->id', $array)->get();
```

you can try it as below too.

```
$array = [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3];
$array = array_values(array_map('strval',$array));
PaymentTransaction::where(function ($query) use ($array) {
   foreach ($array as $id) {
       $query->orWhereJsonContains('payload->ProductCode->id', $id);
   }
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first part of @Dilip's answer is not correct as I had the same issue with `whereJsonContains` on laravel 8. It would return empty result if the field is not a JSON array. The second part of his answer solves the issue but doesn't point the problem here.

The `whereJsonContains` method is used to query `JSON array fields` which in your case, `payload->ProductCode->id` is not an array field. That's why you get empty array.

Now as you are looking for rows that the `payload->ProductCode->id` contained within your `$array`, the `whereIn` method is the method you are looking for.
As Laravel document says, "The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array". So you code would be like this:

```
$array = [ 1, 2, 3];
$myCollection = MyModel::whereIn('payload->ProductCode->id', $array)->get();

// $myCollection contains rows that their `payload->ProductCode->id` is contained within [1, 2, 3] array.
```

You could use `whereJsonContains` method if your data was like this:

```
{
    "ProductCode": {
        "id": ["1", "2"],
        "name": "My Service",
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code that I have written in Eloquent, but you can use Query builder too.

```
$data= [0 =>"Ulcer", 1 => "cough", 2 => "fever"];
Clinic::where('receptionist_id',$request->recptionist_id)->whereJsonContains('data', $data)->get();
```