# How Query Multiple dataset in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am struggling to get list of places that matches current category(multiple dataset) and city:

what i did is the following,

```
 $cat = Category::find($request->category_id)->toArray();

 $cat_id = $cat['id'];
```

and

```
$places = DB::table('places')
    ->where('category',$cat_id)
    ->where('city_id', $request->city_id)
    ->get();
```

See screenshot of the dataset:

[Data in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjFn6.png)

Comment: you did not show your quesiton.what you intend result looks like?

Comment: As I see you have stored `category` as array of strings in places table
but in your `where` clause you are passing `$cat_id` which it seems to be an integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel whereIn implementation of whereJsonContains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483157/laravel-wherein-implementation-of-wherejsoncontains)

Answer (score 0):

For your current problem, you can use the **LIKE** operator.

```
$places = DB::table('places')
->where('category','LIKE', '%"'.$cat_id.'"%')
->where('city_id', $request->city_id)
->get();
```

but the above code will not solve your problem permanently. It looks like you are trying to create a **many to many** relationship in this case the best practice to use pivot tables for this. Better if you could update the schema as an example and follow the Laravel standards to achieve this. Example:

```
table: category_place , having columns ["category_id", "place_id"]
```

in the same way, you need to update the following schema

- Place Type

  table: place_place_type, columns ["place_id", "place_type_id"]
- Amenities

  table: amenity_place, columns ["amenity_id", "place_id"]

Ref. link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks @Aman for the suggestion many to many relationship worked. Thanks